# Writing a Luigi Target as a csv with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pipeline, luigi

I have a basic Luigi pipeline that I'm writing. The pipeline will download Apple stock data and create a CSV out of it. The following is what I've written:

```py
# Download Apple data
class DownloadSymbol(luigi.Task):
    symbol = luigi.Parameter()

    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget(f'data/{symbol.lower()}_data.csv')
    
    def run(self):
        df = download_symbol(self.symbol)
        with self.output().open('w') as csv:
            df.to_csv(csv)
```

I wrote the context manager based on [this article](https://lovethepenguin.com/python-create-an-etl-with-luigi-pandas-and-sqlalchemy-d3cdc9292bc7). But when I run this pipeline, I receive `TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes`. I've tried changing the context manager to be a `wb`-type write, but I receive the same error.

How do I correctly utilize `pd.DataFrame.to_csv()` in a Luigi pipeline?

Comment: What is `download_symbol`, and what is the output of `print(df.head())`?

Comment: @PeterLeimnigler `download_symbol` is a functioning API call function of a stock API. `print(df.head())` confirms that for me.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
with self.output().open('w') as csv: 
    csv.write(df.to_csv())
```